# replacing back slashes in string

Tags: c#

In C# how can I replace the back slashes in the following file path to be a valid path:

I would like to replace:

```
"\\\\foldera\\folderb\\folderc\\Assets.mpg"
```

With:

```
"\\foldera\folderb\folderc\Assets.mpg"
```

Answer (score 2):

try:   `string.replace(@"\\",@"\");`

Comment: This works partially. Now my paths looks like this: \foldera\folderb\folderc\Assets.mpg". I need double back slashes at the  begenning

Answer (score 2):

If that string is referenced by a variable str, then use:

```
str = str.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead -

`@"\foldera\folderb\folder\Assets.mpg"`